# how to navigate from one web site page to another web site page in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have one project module `abc`. It has a web config file. Now I want add one more `.aspx` file to `abc` module. My `.aspx` file has separate web config file. It  will access the data in a different database.

How do I link this file to my module?

Comment: Do you want two different connection string which you want to use on two different pages?

Answer (score 0):

To redirect the user to an other page of your project you can use Response.Redirect :

```
Response.Redirect(string url);
```

Source : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524309(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Generally in ASP.net theres a few solutions to redriecting that I've listed below. I do however have no knowledge of "ABC Module" and can't specifically say anything for that

Using controllers and actions

```
<a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index"> </a>
```

Using standard redirecting

```
<a href=""> </a>
```

Using your controllers (however, will immediately redirect and is probably not what you want)

```
public IActionResult Index { 

   return RedirectToAction("About");
   // OR // 
   Response.Redirect(string url);
   return View();

}
```